# No native symbols in symbol file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, remote-debugging

I am trying to remote debug a Windows Form app with VS2008.

Attaching to process works fine (Remote (Native only with no authentication)), but when I open the modules window and try to load symbols
I get No native symbols in symbol file.

I realise it has something to do with how the app was build but cannot figure out what ?

Answer (score 3):

If it's a Windows Forms app, that implies it's a .NET app?  Then Native debugging is the wrong thing - you're not debugging Native code, but .NET code.  I don't think you can debug .NET code via "No Authentication (native only)" - you're forced to use "Windows Authentication" mode.

Comment: OK I see, then I face a number of firewall problems it seems :(